# passing/retriving multiple rows in 1 click using Angular

Tags: angular

I am able to pass the data in the form of array,but not able to retrive it in form of array. The data that I am passing is not been stored as array in json file.
I used finalList as array , inserting data to it and then pushing it to api using subscriber.

.html code :

```
 <button style="border: 1px solid white" type="button"  name="button"  (click)="add({basic_amount:basic_amount.value,purchase:purchase.value,license:license.value,Particulars:Particulars.value,Quantity :Quantity.value,users :users.value}, regForm)"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
```

.ts code :

```
    add(a, regForm) {
        this.addService.add(a).subscribe((res: Response) => [
             this.finalList.push(a),
             regForm.reset(),
             this.basic_cost
         ]);

  }
```

service to post code :

```
   add(data) {
      const url = 'http://localhost:3000/item';
       const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers});

  }
```

service to get

```
 private URL = 'http://localhost:3000/item';
 item(): Observable <any> {
 console.log('Observable');
 return this.http.get<any>(this.URL);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you want to achieve and where is your problem?

Comment: What is the value of `a` when you use `console.log(a)` at the start of `add()`, before the subscriber-call?

Comment: when I do console.log(a) it displays object that is been passed

Comment: @ThomasSablik I want to pass the array to json file and retrive that array in different component.

Comment: @kedarkulk Where is the json file and how do write into it? Did you check the content of the file after you have written into it? Are you sure that the server sends you an array? Did you check in network monitor (chrome / firefox developer tools)?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? In your code are many unknown, unnecessary variables